# how resize flipbook of turnjs steve jobs sample?

Tags: javascript, css, turnjs

how resize flipbook of turnjs ? , i use steve jobs sample.

i try

```
$("#flipbook").turn("size", 800, 1000);
```

css:

```
#flipbook {
width:800px;
height:1000px
}
```

but not work

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0):

Script it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#flipbook").turn({
    width: 800,
    height: 1000,
    autoCenter: true
});
```